# How to force GHC to evaluate static expression only once

Tags: haskell, optimization

I have a trivial example of SQL-like `join` for ordered lists: if `outer` parameter is `True` then it's union; otherwise it's intersection:

```
import System.Environment

main = do
  [arg] <- getArgs
  let outer = arg == "outer"
  print $ length $ joinLists outer [1..1000] [1,3..1000]

joinLists :: (Ord a, Num a) => Bool -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
joinLists outer xs ys = go xs ys
  where
  go [] _ = []
  go _ [] = []
  go xs@(x:xs') ys@(y:ys') = case compare x y of
    LT -> append x $ go xs' ys
    GT -> append y $ go xs ys'
    EQ -> x : go xs' ys'
  append k = if {-# SCC "isOuter" #-} outer then (k :) else id
```

When I profile it, I see that `isOuter` condition is evaluated every time when `append` is called:

```
stack ghc -- -O2 -prof example.hs && ./example outer +RTS -p && cat example.prof 

                                                     individual      inherited
COST CENTRE MODULE                no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc
MAIN        MAIN                   44          0    0.0   34.6     0.0  100.0
 isOuter    Main                   88        499    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
```

But I'd like the condition to be evaluated only once, so `append` in `go` loop is replaced with either `(k :)` or `id`. Can I force it somehow? Is it related to memoization?

EDIT: Seems like I misinterpreted the profiler output. I added trace to `append` definition:

```
append k = if trace "outer" outer then (k :) else id
```

And `outer` is printed only once.

EDIT2: If I replace `append` with point-free definition, then `if` condition is evaluated only once:

```
 append = if outer then (:) else flip const
```

Comment: I tried `{-# NOINLINE append #-}`, to no effect.

Comment: I think you're misreading the output of the profiler. Your cost centre is the condition of the `if` statement, which is evaluated every time you call `append`, hence the hits to the cost centre. But the thunk that the `outer` variable points to is only evaluated once. If you put your cost centre inside `arg == "outer"` then you should see it only being hit once.

Comment: If you don't want the `if` condition to be evaluated multiple times, you could manually float it to the outside of the loop. `joinLists outer = go (if outer then (:) else flip const)` and redefine `go` to take an extra argument for `append`, rather than referring to its closure. I can't predict whether that'd be faster for your inputs.

Comment: What happens if you define append like this: `append = if outer then (:) else flip const`? (I would test it myself, but I don't have GHC here right now.)

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson and duplode thanks for your comments, they practically answer my question (see the edits).

Comment: @duplode see above

Comment: If your actual goal is to make `joinLists` efficient, then you certainly don't want a call to the unknown function `append` in your inner loop.

Comment: @ReidBarton I suppose the only way to not use `append` function is to have two separate definitions for `go`, e.g. `goInner` and `goOuter`? That would be too premature optimization in my case, especially since in "real world" case I have both `outerLeft` and `outerRight`.

Comment: Yes, you'd have to manually "specialize" and create two (or four) copies of `joinLists`. Since you are already looking at this with the profiler, it seems like mature optimization to me.

Comment: Actually, I lied. You could write `joinListsGeneric` which takes the `append` function as a parameter, have two cases in `joinLists` that pass the two possible functions in, and rely on inlining.

Comment: @ReidBarton thanks for `joinListsGeneric` suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try pushing lambdas inwards:

```
append = if {-# SCC "isOuter" #-} outer then \k -> (k :) else \k -> id
```

The original code is essentially `\k -> if outer ...` which takes the argument first, and tests the guard later. The code above instead tests the guard *before* taking the argument.

Alternative:

```
append | outer     = \k -> (k :) 
       | otherwise = \k -> id
```

One can further simplify those lambdas to a more readable form.

Comment: As an aside, `\k -> (k :)` is just `(:)`, but I like the symmetry with `\k -> id` (rather than `const id`).